# python exact match of column value in csv files

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a csv file containing several rows and columns. 
I would like to filter my file using python 3.4 and create a new file with exact match of certain values in rows. My problem is that I am choosing 2 columns to filter the rows by: if EQA nb matches with the exact name of the organization from the list, copy that row to the new file.

My file look like that:

```
EQA_nb,organization,a,b,c,d
16,TCS,a1,b1,c1,d1
14,LS,a2,b2,c2,d2
14,BMC,a3,b3,c3,d3
2,TLS,a4,b4,c4,d4
6,LCHC,a5,b5,c5,d5
14,TLS,a6,b6,c6,d6
etc..
```

My code is:

```
import csv
with open ('data.csv','w',newline='') as outf, open('output.csv','r', newline='')as inf:
    reader = csv.DictReader(inf, delimiter=',')
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outf, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames, delimiter=',')
    writer.writeheader()

    for row in reader:
        if ((row["EQA_nb"]== '6' and row["organization"] in "EP, LCHC, SP")
                or (row["EQA_nb"]== "2" and row["organization"] in "AMC, LCHC, SGPLP, TCS, TLS")
                or (row["EQA_nb"]== "7" and row["organization"] in "GP")
                or (row["EQA_nb"]== "8" and row["organization"] in "LFMC")
                or (row["EQA_nb"]== "9" and row["organization"] in "LS")
                or (row["EQA_nb"]== "11" and row["organization"] in "DP, WSS")
                or (row["EQA_nb"]== "13" and row["organization"] in "TRP")
                or (row["EQA_nb"]== "14" and row["organization"] in "BMC,TLS")): 

            writer.writerow(row)
```

I would like to get the new file showing exact match of the row value specified i.e. showing 14 TLS but not 14 LS for example as the current code shows.
thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
'BMC,TLS'
```

with

```
['BMP', 'TLS']
```

then

```
row['organization'] in ['BMP', 'TLS']
```

will match 'TLS' but not 'LS'.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done quite neatly by putting the matches into a dictionary, reducing the if/elif chain to a single lookup, which in turn can be optimised using [operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).

```
import csv
import operator


mapping = {
    "6": ["EP", "LCHC", "SP"],
    "2": ["AMC", "LCHC", "SGPLP", "TCS", "TLS"],
    "7": ["GP"],
    "8": ["LFMC"],
    "9": ["LS"],
    "11": ["DP", "WSS"],
    "13": ["TRP"],
    "14": ["BMC", "TLS"],
}


kv = operator.itemgetter("EQA_nb", "organization")


with open("data.csv", "w", newline="") as outf, open("output.csv", "r", newline="") as inf:
    reader = csv.DictReader(inf, delimiter=",")
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outf, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames, delimiter=",")
    writer.writeheader()

    for row in reader:
        eqa, org = kv(row)
        if org in mapping.get(eqa, []):
            writer.writerow(row)
```